# How to use RestClient to get bearer token generation?

Tags: c#, rest-client

I have to generate the bearer token using token end point in azure how can I do that using RESTClient in C# .NET?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your Bearer token to client Header like that.

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```